# SQL Server function to get count of night hours between two dates

Tags: sql-server

I have to calculate the night hours between two dates. SQL Server:

I have the following situation:

```
@date1=2021-06-01 05:00:00.000
@date2=2021-06-03 05:00:00.000
```

I need to get the night hours, between 22:00:00 and 06:00:00

For the @date1 and @date2 I need to get the result: 16 hours.

```
2021-06-01 05:00:00.000 to 2021-06-01 06:00:00.000 - 1.0 hour
2021-06-01 22:00:00.000 to 2021-06-02 06:00:00.000 - 8.0 hour
2021-06-02 22:00:00.000 to 2021-06-03 05:00:00.000 - 7.0 hour
```

Example 2:

```
@date1=2021-06-22 04:55:00.000
@date2=2021-06-22 16:45:00.000
```

I need to get the following result: 1.083333 hours

The result should be in maximum 6 decimals.
More than 4 days will not be.

What suggestion can you give me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: It is always 8 hours for full days. You just need to adjust for the first and last day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Turn the range between the two dates into a set.
2. Extract the DATEPART(HOUR) for the start and end of each hour.
3. Count the hour only when it ends <= 6 or starts >= 22

This is the query I ended up with, assuming you really won't go beyond a 4-day (96-hour) range. You will need a `MAXRECURSION` hint if your range goes above 100 hours:

```
/*  basic test harness - just change @test to change the range to use  */
DECLARE @test int = 1, @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime, @lb datetime;

SELECT @d1 = d1, @d2 = d2, @lb = SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(
      YEAR(d1),MONTH(d1),DAY(d1),DATEPART(HOUR,d1),0) 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  (1, '2021-06-01T05:00:00.000', '2021-06-03T05:00:00.000'),
  (2, '2021-06-22T04:55:00.000', '2021-06-22T16:45:00.000'),
  (3, '2021-06-01T10:50:00.000', '2021-06-01T22:50:00.000'))
  AS t(t,d1,d2)) AS t WHERE t = @test;

;WITH n(d) AS     (
  SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @lb) UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 1, d) FROM n WHERE d < @d2
), 
d(d) AS     (
  SELECT d FROM n UNION ALL SELECT d FROM (VALUES(@d1),(@d2)) AS v(d)
), 
seg(s, e, starting_hour, ending_hour, diff_seconds) AS     (
  SELECT LAG(d,1) OVER (ORDER BY d), d, 
      DATEPART(HOUR, LAG(d,1) OVER (ORDER BY d)), 
      DATEPART(HOUR, d), DATEDIFF(SECOND, LAG(d,1) OVER (ORDER BY d), d) 
  FROM d
),     src AS 
(
  SELECT *, count_it = CASE 
    WHEN (ending_hour <= 6 OR starting_hour >= 22) AND e <= @d2
        THEN COALESCE(diff_seconds,0)/60/60.0 ELSE 0 END 
  FROM seg
)
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(12,6), SUM(count_it)) FROM src;
```

Result for `@test = 1` ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c3a79a3b2882bf850c589e22d56fc51c)), `@test = 2` ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cea81fb90e5281ad695e998e64a74b51)), `@test = 3` ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=295eafb635411069286b16be9d82d549)):

```
        1               2               3    
---------       ---------       ---------
16.000000        1.083333        0.833333
```

If you want to avoid recursion, you can create a function to generate a series of numbers (some great background info [in this series](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/04/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-4)); I chose a simple one for SQL 2016+:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums_Split(@low bigint,@high bigint)
RETURNS table AS RETURN
  WITH spaces AS (SELECT REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max),' '),
          CONVERT(integer, CEILING(SQRT(CONVERT(float, 
          IIF(@high >= @low, @high - @low + 1, 0)))))) AS spc),
       splt AS (SELECT CONVERT(bit,NULL) b FROM spaces 
          CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(spaces.spc,' ')),
       Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) AS rownum 
          FROM splt AS A, splt AS B)
    SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) rownum AS rn, 
        @high + 1 - rownum AS op,
        @low - 1 + rownum AS n
    FROM Nums ORDER BY rownum;
GO
```

Then you can just replace the first CTE with this:

```
;WITH n(d) AS     (
  SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, n, @lb) 
    FROM dbo.GetNums_Split(1,DATEDIFF(HOUR, @lb, @d2)-1)
),
```

Comment: Everything is good, thank you very much for your solution.